# awakeFromNib method called multiple times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, interface-builder, xib

In my NSPersistenDocument based project i have a structure like this

```
myDocument (NSPersistentDocument) -> myDocument.xib (windows xib)
                                           |
                                           |-> view (the self.view) --> ... "other view"
                                           |
                                           |-> some NSArrayController 
                                           |
                                           |-> myResourceViewController --> myResourceViewController.xib
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |-> view (the self.view)
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |-> myTreeController (a NSTreeController subclass)
```

basically, myResourceViewController is an instance of a viewController who manage resourceView and manage their data.

in awakeFromNib method of myDocument i have the following code

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    ...
    [leftBar addSubview:resourceViewController.view]; //i add resourceViewController's view 
    resourceViewController.view.frame = leftBar.bounds;
    ...
}
```

in myResourceViewController awakeFromNib methods i have:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);

    [removeButton bind:@"enabled" toObject:resourceTreeController withKeyPath:@"selection" options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSIsNotNilTransformerName forKey:NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption]];

    NSArray *draggedTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ResourceURIPasteBoardType, nil];
    [resourceOutlineView registerForDraggedTypes:draggedTypes];
}
```

the NSLog say that awakeFromNib, of the same instance of myResourceViewController, is called 4 time, i don't understand why. My only ResourceViewController is created in myDocument xib. I don't use NSNib loading methods everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same object? Try `NSLog(@"%p %@", self, [self description])`.

Comment: Yes, i check with NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);

Comment: Is myDocument.xib is the only nib?

Comment: No, myResourceViewController have a xib called myResourceViewController.xib.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the solution. `awakeFromNib` is called every time a `NSTableCellView` is created by `NSOutlineView`.

Comment: Ok, it was so obvious in my case that awakeFromNib is called # of cells times .. But, what's the work around? Subclass NSTableCellView?

Comment: Very infuriating, anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: It's a workaround, but I set a BOOL initialize = NO in my init, then only execute the code in awakeFromNib when initialize = NO (and set it to YES within that if statement)

Comment: On 10.8 you can use registerNib:forIdentifier: so that it will be a different nib loading the cellview.

Comment: @Mazyod The solution is not to set the `owner` to `self` in `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`

Comment: @NSAddict That makes sense, but I am hooking the cell with the file owner as the delegate :( [yeah, I am still woking on the same app. Submitted an update yesterday]

Comment: @Mazyod What delegate methods do you use?

Comment: @NSAddict Oops, I am using that for iOS, where the cells are actually created in separate XIB files. Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem today. Not using `self` as owner with `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` actually works. But are there no side effects if the owner is set e.g. to `nil`? The documentation is not a big help here. Also the question and answer should be updated to reflect the new knowledge.

Comment: If it is a requirement that something only run once, just wrap it in a `dispatch_once` block.

Answer (score 8):

The root cause is described in the NSTableView header file of the method makeViewWithIdentifier: " .... Note that 'owner' will get an 'awakeFromNib:' call each time the object is instantiated."

My solution is simple but I expect not suitable for all: Just define e.g. the tabelView as owner:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:kTextViewIdentifier owner:tableView];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: When loading a prototype view it is admissible to simply pass nil for the owner.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why it's called four times, but at least I can account for two calls of `awakeFromNib`. It's important to remember that `awakeFromNib` is called even for the File's Owner of the nib file, not only the objects contained in the nib file.

Therefore, your ResourceViewController's awakeFromNib gets called at least twice: when it is loaded in myDocument.xib, and then when the view managed by the ResourceViewController is loaded from another nib.

It's better to perform the initialization in other methods which is called on a more definite timing, such as `...didLoad` or `applicationDidFinish...`.

Answer (score 1):

I put the code within a synchronized block inside my awakeFromNib like so.

e.g

```
@implementation {
    BOOL _initialize;
}

    - (id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _initialize = YES;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (_initialize) {
                _initialize = NO;

                /* code to execute once */
            }
        }

        /* code to re-execute */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same in NSTableView. NSTableView was updated through NSArrayController and I noticed that NSTableView had delegate set to File Owner, When I removed delegate to File Owner, awakeFromNib called only once.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't easy to figure out but for me somehow I my table view changed to 'View Based' vs 'Cell Based' for the Content Mode.

Switching back to 'Cell Based' and the awakeFromNib only ran once.

Note: select your table view in Interface Builder three times to get to the right level.  Or, just select your 'Table View' from the Documents Outline.

[image: Xcode Attributes Inspector]

Comment: I'm using xcode 5.0.2 and I can't find the property "Content Mode" of my table, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to set the owner to self in `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`

This makes the awakefromNib to be called multiple times.