# Block gets executed twice on async thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa

I have a weird issue. I have a class that calls a method in another class on a background thread, but it fetches data twice on Thread 2 and then once it finishes puts it to thread 4 for example. Does anyone know why?

Class that calls the method:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSString *swedbankRate;

    CurrencyViewHelper *currencyRates = [[CurrencyViewHelper alloc]init];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        swedbankRate = [currencyRates getSwedbankRates];
        NSLog(@"%@", swedbankRate);
    });
```

So the part from the CurrencyViewHelper is:

-(NSString *)getSwedbankRates
{

```
// Set to empty String in case there is some issue
swedbankRate = @"";

// Get Data from Swedbank
NSString *swedbankURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.swedbank.ee/private/d2d/payments2/rates/currency?language=EST"]
                                                 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                    error:nil];
NSArray *swedbankArray = [swedbankURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"<tr>"];
NSString *swedbankString = swedbankArray[18];
swedbankArray = [swedbankString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<tr>"];

NSString *swedbankDirty = swedbankArray[0];

// Check if the fetched data corresponds to RUB data
if ([swedbankDirty containsString:@"RUB"]) {

    swedbankDirty = [swedbankDirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<td class=\"numeric-cell\">"
                                                             withString:@""];
    swedbankDirty = [swedbankDirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                             withString:@""];
    swedbankDirty = [swedbankDirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                             withString:@""];
    NSArray *swedbankCleanArray = [swedbankDirty componentsSeparatedByString:@"</td>"];
    swedbankDirty = swedbankCleanArray[4];

    // Set result to value fetched from internet
    swedbankRate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [swedbankDirty floatValue]];

}
```

And result is

```
2015-12-07 14:26:29.635 Photography[60338:18355297] 71.14
2015-12-07 14:26:29.684 Photography[60338:18355293] 71.14
```

I cant put my finger on it why does it get executed twice?

What the method is supposed to do is scan the HTML code of a webpage and get just one float number from the whole content for me to use later. Ye the code isnt perfect, still learning. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: If it's running twice it's because `awakeFromNib` is being called twice.  I'd add a log in that method to verify.  Then I'd move the code someplace else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `awakeFromNib` is called twice in your app... ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092366/2012216))

Answer (score 1):

awakeFromNib is usually not a good place for that kind of thing. You should use awakeFromNib to do things that you would have wanted to do in Interface Builder, but for some reason couldn't - so just to fix problems that arise when you load a nib file.

For example, doing things in awakeFromNib gets you into trouble if you use the same class in a different context, and if you build a user interface in code instead of using a nib file, and your awakeFromNib doesn't get called at all anymore.

Comment: I was mostly trying to populate labels with some data which i cant do until i get this data from the webpage, thats why i wanted to put this whole thing in awake from nib. But view did load and waiting a split secodn for values to update to new ones isnt that bad either.

Answer (score 0):

You are both correct. Wow, what a silly mistake to make. Indeed another class was also calling awakeFromNib to do its stuff there too.

I put those calls in the viewDidLoad method and it is working as it needs now! Great! What a great way to learn this multithreading stuff! :)